# Making a list of buttons in using perl TK based ona loop

Tags: arrays, loops, perl, button, tk-toolkit

I have a loop of items in an array that looks like this:

```
("Hugo", "Gilbert", "Linda", "Katrina")
```

What I am trying to do is design a perl Tk script that allows me to create a number of radio buttons in based on what is in the array, which would look like below:

```
<> Hugo
<> Gilbert
<> Linda
<> Katrina
```

When I click on each button I should get a popup message saying "You selected Hugo" if I clicked on Hugo.

Below is the snippet of code in which I was attempting to accomplish this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# 
use Tk;
use strict;

my $mw = MainWindow->new;
$mw->geometry("200x500");
$mw->title("Button Test");


my @items = ("Hugo", "Gilbert", "Linda", "Katrina");

foreach my $item(@items) {
    print "$item\n";
    $mw->Radiobutton(-text => "$item", -command => \&button1_sub)->pack();
}


sub button1_sub {
  my $button=@_;
  $mw->messageBox(-message => "$button Pushed", -type => "ok");
}
MainLoop;
```

I am not getting the desired results form this code.  How do I tweak the code in order to get the results I described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. This line

   ```
   my $button = @_;
   ```

   is a scalar assignment, it evaluates the `@_` array in scalar context, i.e. assigns its size to `$button`. As you can see, it's 0, i.e. the array is empty - the sub doesn't get any arguments.
2. As mentioned above, you need to pass an argument to the callback. There are two possible ways:

   ```
   # Array syntax
   $mw->Radiobutton(-text => $item,
                    -command => [\&button1_sub, $item]
   ```

   or

   ```
   # Subroutine syntax
   $mw->Radiobutton(-text => $item,
                    -command => sub { button1_sub($item) }
   ```

As you can see, I removed double quotes from `"$item"`. They are redundant here, you can use the variable directly.

E.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Tk;

my $mw = MainWindow->new;
$mw->geometry('200x500');
$mw->title('Button Test');

my @items = qw( Hugo Gilbert Linda Katrina );

for my $item (@items) {
    $mw->Radiobutton(-text    => $item,
                     -command => [\&button1_sub, $item]
    )->pack;
}

sub button1_sub {
  my ($button) = @_;
  $mw->messageBox(-message => "$button Pushed",
                  -type    => 'ok');
}
MainLoop();
```

Comment: I tried to do that but unfortunately I got the variable button passed as a instead of the name of the item selected.

Comment: I mean to say that I get a 1 for the output instead of the variable value which should either be Hugo, Gilbert, etc. depending on what choice I select.  Is that what you got?  I am not getting that result, I only get returned a 1.

Comment: Fixed the problem.  I had to modify the button assignment in the subroutine to look like this  my $button="@_";  Thank you for your help.